# Adding a reference assembly to script task and deploying

Tags: c#, sharepoint, ssis, sharepoint-2010, script-task

I'm working on an SSIS project which contains a single script task. The job of the script task is to upload a text file to a SharePoint site library. I'm using Microsft.SharePoint.Client and Microsoft.SharePoint.Runtime to achieve this. The code is very simple.

```
string sharePointSite = @"https://server.com";

            using (ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(sharePointSite))
            {
                Web currentWeb = ctx.Web;

                ctx.Load(currentWeb);

                ctx.ExecuteQuery();

                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"Z:\samplefile.txt", FileMode.Open))
                {
                    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(ctx, "/sites/subsite/Library/TestFile from client.txt", fs, true);

                }

                Console.WriteLine("Uploaded File Successfully");
            }
```

This works as expected from visual studio. Now if I package this to a different server,I'm not sure if the dll's will be packaged along with the deployment file. I have set the 'copy local' property of reference to true. In a .NET application, the  dll file usually gets copied on to the bin folder. But in case of a SSIS script task, where should I look for the copied dll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure all dll's referenced by your SSIS script component are deployed in Prod server under "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\"
SSIS Package will not move those dll's.